# How do I pull data into a new Excel worksheet table from the Data Model?

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I'm using Power Query to pull data into the excel Data Model.

And I'm using Power Pivot and CUBEx functions to pull useful data into my worksheets.

But I can't see a simple way to pull a table into a worksheet from data in the Data Model.

Do people just use Power Queries to do this?  I'm clearly misunderstanding a key concept.

In my mind, I think of the flow as:

- Raw Data (sometimes in the same excel file in a tab) or External Database - then:
- Power Query and M-Language to pull that data and clean up, and put it in the Data Model - then:
- Data Model and DAX to create relationships and useful Measures - then:
- Power Pivot and Cube functions to interact with that data in a worksheet.

But - how to I pull a table from the Data Model and put it in a Worksheet??

Thanks.

I'm trying Power Pivot and Cube functions to interact with that data in a worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

In Power Pivot (Date model), click on `PivotTable` under the Home tab in the ribbon. Then select Flattened PivotTable.

[image]